# nanoGPT with custom dataset

Tags: python, large-language-model, gpt-2

I am trying to use nanoGPT from https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT on my custom input file.

I have posted this issue on the repo itself  ( at [issue 172](https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT/issues/172) ) but not getting any response there, hence lookin for some advice here on stackoverflow.

Following the same steps as described here for the Shakespere input file, I tried this on a custom input file which contains multiple paragraphs with different headings. The file contents looks like this

```
Heading 1
Some information related to heading 1 goes here

Heading 2
Some information related to heading 2 goes here
```

Containing 20 such paragraphs.

The "prepare.py" and "train.py" file executed successfully for this input file.
However, when I try to generate one sample, the output is some incorrect english like this

```
paceliYai ominger fromally.Satexas Stence taly mand gollag adeppirirhon temas poymais,Mcenterted Should had & days to suratication tEO - ande ymanaN tor reeson travel from the enterns tleat sompoyers asubve the candidate can travel cof grotef dosiction of inotis, an too coan cile verand ginald to Employees. All embent ire thang falor ind the to pacomvertaly of the is enotiry for
```

Is this input dataset format correct? Or something specific is needed?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that you have set the directory to your custom prepared data correct. You can sanity check with another custom dataset such as tiny_schiller, [here](https://github.com/schutera/tiny_schiller).

Two ideas,

1. Your data is maybe not enough to [train](https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT/blob/master/train.py) this model from scratch.

**Solution.. is to resume training on gpt2 with your own data**

```
init_from = 'resume' # 'scratch' or 'resume' or 'gpt2*'
```

2. Your training did not converge yet

**Solution .. is to log your training to see whether you converged, or blindly try to train longer**